# R programming student's newman keul's test with GAD package

Tags: r, analysis

I'm getting an error :

> "Error in if (colnames(tm.class)[j] == "fixed") tm.final[i, j] = 0 :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

all I tried to do was a simple `snk.test(lm(values ~ factor1*factor2))`, and the estimates function keeps returning this error. I'm not sure what tm. class is, but I have no idea why the column names seem to be NA for whatever the estimates function is testing. I'm a beginner at R and don't really know how to debug a prewritten function.

**OK EDIT:**
I have my data in a text file, it looks like this

variable | factor1 | factor2
x1       |  f1   |   f2
x2       |  f12  |   f22
etc. (all values are just decimals).

All i did was read.table from the file, then call `snk.test(lm(variable ~ factor1*factor2, data=data))` and get the aforementioned error message.

Comment: How do you expect us to be able to help if all you offer is an error message?

Comment: uhh i added some more information. Not sure exactly what one would look for in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an estimation operation that involves only two factors then you should FIRST look at the real data-layout. You didn't include enough code to know what the name of the dataframe was and I surely do hope you didn't make the colossal error of using `attach`:

```
 with( datafrm , table( fac1, fact2) )
```

My guess is that you will find one or more tables where it makes no sense to estimate whatever `snk.test` might be testing.